# Issue in converting a HTML Link to Drupal Link using l() function

Tags: navigation

I have created a HTML anchor link. Now i need to convert this link to Drupal's link using `l()` function. But i am not getting what i want. I am new to this Drupal environment.

HTML Link :

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadQtiPlayer('.$targetPath.','.$targetWindowHeight.','.$targetWindowWidth.')" id="qtiStatQuiz1">'.START_QTIQUIZ.'</a>
```

What i have tried is,

```
l('Start QTI Quiz', '#', array('','onclick' => "loadQtiPlayer('.$targetPath.','.$targetWindowHeight.','.$targetWindowWidth.')"));
```

This is not working. I am using **Drupal 6.14.**

Can anyone point out where is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$current_path = check_url(drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));
$onclick = 'loadQtiPlayer(' . $targetPath . ',' . $targetWindowHeight . ',' . $targetWindowWidth . ')';
print l('Start QTI Quiz', $current_path, array('fragment' => ' ', 'attributes' => array('onclick' => $onclick)));
```

Comment: EDIT: added `filter_xss` instead of `check_url`... Not sure which is more safe/efficient in this case. :/

Comment: Wow.. Works like a charm. Thank you man for this awesome answer.

Comment: Use check_url(), filter_xss() is for escaping HTML from content that will be displayed on the screen.

Comment: @rooby Thanks... I figured as much, if for no other reason than less resource-intensive. In fact that's how I originally had it posted, but-- well the "but" is not important... Changing back. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `fragment` option to add a fragment to the URL. `l()` makes it pretty difficult to get an empty fragment, but you can get very close to it with a little  hack:

```
$link = l('Start QTI Quiz', '', array('fragment' => ' ', 'external' => TRUE)));
```

That'll do the trick for Drupal 6 & 7.

Answer (score 0):

In this case as the href is pointing at any content there's no point in using the l() function at all. You may as well code the A tag directly as it's not really a link.