# How to set Form API link href to # hashtag

Tags: 7, forms

In Form API when creating a link, the output a-anchor will have a prefix of "en/" in front of whatever I set as the href value and if href is set to "#" it will be output with the language prefix and # is escaped and becomes a code something like "en/%23"

this is the code:

```
$element['add_address'] = array(
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#title' => t('Add new address'),
            '#href' => '#',
        );
```

I need that link to not have a href destination value, as it's supposed to react to javascript only. I know I could do a preventDefault() or any of the same resulting bypasses with JS, but I'm curious how to make a empty anchor with the form API.

Thanks,

Alari

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an EMPTY anchor-only link with l()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/how-to-create-an-empty-anchor-only-link-with-l)

Comment: No, but Clive's comment under one of the answers did in May 2017, unfortunately it was never posted as an answer.

Comment: Could you then maybe post it as an answer and accept it to help future readers to find the right solution for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Clive (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) answer in the comments:

```
'#href' => '', '#options' => array('fragment' => ' ', 'external' => TRUE)
```

in the render array solves the issue and removes the pre-processing with the language prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, give this a try

```
'#href' => '&num',  OR  '#href' =>'&#x00023', OR '#href' => '&#35',
```

Comment: 'twill not, the `#` representing numbers and `&` will also be escaped. Drupal doesn't have a method for adding an empty fragment believe it or not. There are a couple of hacks, I'll see if I can dig one up

Comment: @Clive I had a similar problem with Twig [Twig: How to print special symbols, such as Copyright, Trademark, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880446/twig-how-to-print-special-symbols-such-as-copyright-trademark-etc#comment-61326988#answer-36880514) thought the character code solution there may work here. I guess after thinking it over, you're right.

Comment: Yes, unfortunetely these don't work either and if they did, they wouldn't escape the prefix, which I don't seem to be able to control at all. @Clive: Would be very interested in seeing a solution :) So far google hasn't been of much help to my queries..

Comment: I think this is the canonical post @AlariTruuts: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/how-to-create-an-empty-anchor-only-link-with-l

Comment: @Clive: Thanks, I actually found that one on my search as well, but don't see how I could use it in the scenario described. I tried setting the #href to "javascript:void(0)" but that came out as: "/en/javascript%3Avoid%280%29" any ideas how to escape the prefix?

Comment: Errrrr...try `'#href' => '', '#options' => array('fragment' => ' ', 'external' => TRUE)` in the render array

Comment: @Clive: You're a very smart person :)! the solution works, mind if you mark it as an answer, so I can accept? it puts the href out as "# " with the following space, curious as to why that is, but works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this to create a link:

```
  l(t('My Anchor Link'), '', array(
     'fragment' => ' ',        // use a space here
     'external' => TRUE,      // this will solve your problem
     'attributes' => array(
        'title' => 'Title description'
   )
```

Comment: It would be helpful to use the same render array, which should be possible by including that array as the #options element.