# create empty link

Tags: 8, navigation

I am using the following code.

```
$url = Url::fromUri('javascript:', array('external' => true));
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t("#action"), $url)->toString();
```

It causes the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The URI 'javascript' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri() (line 280 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal826\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Url.php).

Is this supported in Drupal 8?

I found [How to create an EMPTY anchor-only link with l()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/how-to-create-an-empty-anchor-only-link-with-l) but that is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Did you add the use statements at the top of your code? `use Drupal\Core\Url;` and `use Drupal\Core\Link;` ?

Comment: yes added both `use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;`

Comment: If you read the [public static function Url::fromUri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x), there is no such thing as `external`, I think you're looking for `fragment` and also `javascript:` is not a URI.

Comment: I want the final result to be like this:`<a href="javascript:;">#link</a>`

Comment: I don't think you can, why do you need `javascript:;` there anyways?

Comment: I was of the view that it would be backwards compatible with the drupal 7 `l()` function, anyways I have switched to using button for my purpose, thanks

Answer (score 4):

So we create url for link which should be empty.

For this we can use `::fromUserInput()` and send parameters starting with `#` or `/`.

Or create url from route `::fromRoute('<none>')` with specific token.

`$url = Url::fromUserInput('#');`

Way to create link is usual for D8:

`$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($this->t('Some link'), $url);`

Comment: Did you got any errors?

Comment: `Url::fromUserInput('#')` does not work. It does create an "empty" link, but the goal is to get a link with `href="#"`, which is not the result.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is this:

```php
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;

// A value that would inject HTML if you just used string interpolation.
$value_needing_sanitize = '"><h1>BAD</h1><a href="#" class="';

// Optionally add attributes with any HTML sanitized.
$attributes = new Attribute([
  'data-input' => $value_needing_sanitize,
]);

// Create the anchor tag.
$link = <<<HTML
  <a href="#" $attributes>
HTML . $this->t('Click here') . '</a></span>';

// Render array
$render_array = ['#markup' => $link];
```

If you don't need any attributes set to user input, then you can remove those parts and just create the anchor tag and render array.